# Removing the Lambda Basic Execution Role from all the functions at once

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda

How can we remove the Lambda Basic Execution Role from all the AWS functions at once? Is there any option to prevent users from selecting the Lambda Basic Execution role from the list of roles?

I have tried manually going to a specific function and delete it. But there are many functions from which it needs to be deleted.

Comment: No, there is no way to remove it from multiple lambdas at once. You can obviously write a script for that. If you want to restrict users from using that policy you *can* write an SCP for that, not sure why that would be useful though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove role from all functions at once (AWS Managed Roles).

This bash script can help you to do it. Firstly create a role match with your needs and copy it's ARN.

```bash
functions=$(aws lambda list-functions --region us-east-2  --query 'Functions[?ends_with(Role, `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole`) == `true`].FunctionName')
for i in "${functions[@]}"
do
   #update functions 1-by-1 
   aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name "$i" --role "YOUR_NEW_ROLE_ARN"
   echo "role updated $i"
done
```